# How to test an inner Observable that will not complete?

Tags: rxjs, jestjs, redux-observable

I'm using `jest` to test a `redux-observable` epic that forks off an inner observable created using `Observable.fromEvent` and listens for a specific keypress before emitting an action.

I'm struggling to test for when the inner Observable does not receive this specific keypress and therefore does not emit an action.

Using jest, the following times out:

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs'
import { ActionsObservable } from 'redux-observable'
import keycode from 'keycode'

const closeOnEscKeyEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType('LISTEN_FOR_ESC').switchMapTo(
        Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup')
            .first(event => keycode(event) === 'esc')
            .mapTo({ type: 'ESC_PRESSED' })
    )

const testEpic = ({ setup, test, expect }) =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
        const input$ = new Subject()
        setup(new ActionsObservable(input$))
            .toArray()
            .subscribe(resolve)
        test(input$)
    }).then(expect)

// This times out
it('no action emitted if esc key is not pressed', () => {
    expect.assertions(1)
    return testEpic({
        setup: input$ => closeOnEscKeyEpic(input$),
        test: input$ => {
            // start listening
            input$.next({ type: 'LISTEN_FOR_ESC' })

            // press the wrong keys
            const event = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
                keyCode: keycode('p'),
            })
            const event2 = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
                keyCode: keycode('1'),
            })
            global.document.dispatchEvent(event)
            global.document.dispatchEvent(event2)

            // end test
            input$.complete()
        },
        expect: actions => {
            expect(actions).toEqual([])
        },
    })
})
```

My expectation was that calling `input$.complete()` would cause the promise in `testEpic` to resolve, but for this test it does not.

I feel like I'm missing something. Does anyone understand why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still new to Rx/RxJS, so my apologies if the terminology of this answer is off. I was able to reproduce your scenario, though.

The inner observable (`Observable.fromEvent`) is blocking the outer observable. The completed event on your `ActionsObservable` doesn't propagate through until after the inner observable is completed.

Try out the following code snippet with this test script:

1. Run the code snippet.
2. Press a non-Escape key.

   - Nothing should be printed to the console.
3. Select the "Listen for Escape!" button.
4. Press a non-Escape key.

   - The keyCode should be printed to the console.
5. Select the "Complete!" button.
6. Press a non-Escape key.

   - The keyCode should be printed to the console.
7. Press the Escape key.

   - The keyCode should be printed to the console
   - The onNext callback should print the ESC_PRESSED action to the console.
   - The onComplete callback should print to the console.

```js
document.getElementById('complete').onclick = onComplete
document.getElementById('listenForEsc').onclick = onListenForEsc

const actions = new Rx.Subject()

const epic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    Rx.operators.filter(action => action.type === 'LISTEN_FOR_ESC'),
    Rx.operators.switchMapTo(
      Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup').pipe(
        Rx.operators.tap(event => { console.log('keyup: %s', event.keyCode) }),
        Rx.operators.first(event => event.keyCode === 27), // escape
        Rx.operators.mapTo({ type: 'ESC_PRESSED' }),
      )
    )
  )

epic(actions.asObservable()).subscribe(
  action => { console.log('next: %O', action) },
  error => { console.log('error: %O', error) },
  () => { console.log('complete') },
)

function onListenForEsc() {
  actions.next({ type: 'LISTEN_FOR_ESC' })
}

function onComplete() {
  actions.complete()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.0/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
<button id="complete">Complete!</button>
<button id="listenForEsc">Listen for Escape!</button>
```

Neither the `switchMapTo` marble diagram [nor its textual documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMapTo)) clearly indicate what happens when the source observable completes before the inner observable. However, the above code snippet demonstrates exactly what you observed in the Jest test.

[image: switchMapTo marble diagram]

I believe this answers your "why" question, but I'm not sure I have a clear solution for you. One option could be to [hook in a cancellation action](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/Cancellation.html) and use `takeUntil` on the inner observable. But, that might feel awkward if that's only ever used in your Jest test.

I can see how this epic/pattern wouldn't be a problem in a real application as, commonly, epics are created and subscribed to once without ever being unsubscribed from. However, depending on the specific scenario (e.g. creating/destroying the store multiple times in a single application), I could see this leading to hung subscriptions and potential memory leaks. Good to keep in mind!